# Is possible cast from a preprocessor to array?

Tags: c, arrays, casting, preprocessor

I am trying to cast a preprocesor to an array, But I am not sure if it is possible at all,

Where for example I have defined:
Number 0x44332211

Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define number 0x44332211

int main()
{

   uint8_t array[4] = {(uint8_t)number, (uint8_t)number << 8,(uint8_t)(number <<16 ),(uint8_t)(number <<24)};

    printf("array[%x] \n\r",array[0]);  // 0x44
    printf("array[%x] \n\r",array[1]);  // 0x33
    printf("array[%x] \n\r",array[2]);  // 0x22
    printf("array[%x] \n\r",array[3]);  // 0x11

    return 0;
}
```

and I want to cast it two an uint8_t array[4] where array[0] = 0x44, array[1] = 0x33, array[2] = 0x22, array[3] = 0x11

Is it possible?

```
my output:
array[11]                                                                                                                                      
array[0]                                                                                                                                       
array[0]                                                                                                                                       
array[0]
```

Comment: You're shifting in the wrong direction.

Comment: You're also casting before shifting, which is probably not what you intended.  `(uint8_t)0x44332211 << 8` gives you `0x00001100`, and when you put that into a `uint8_t` variable, you get `0`.

Comment: now I am casting after shifting to >> but I am still getting 0s

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/7f6W9t). Please update the question with a [mcve] including the changes that you've made.

Comment: You're still casting before shifting in the "<<8" case, and all of your shifts are the wrong direction.  You want `(uint8_t)(number >> _n_)`

Comment: ^ the cast is redundant and obscures the code readability

Comment: @M.M Casting to the intended type instead of having an implicit lvalue conversion is good practice. Means that you have actually considered what the code does and didn't just get it right by undocumented luck. Robust code doesn't contain _any_ implicit conversions, but only explicit casts. C is simply dysfunctional and dangerous when it comes to type conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of realizations are needed:

- `uint8_t` masks out the least significant byte of the data. Meaning you have to right shift data down into the least significant byte, not left shift data away from it.
- `0x44332211` is an *integer constant*, not a "preprocessor". It is of type `int` and therefore signed. You shouldn't use bitwise operators on signed types. Easily solved by changing to `0x44332211u` with unsigned suffix.
- Typo here: `(uint8_t)number << 8`. You should shift then cast. Casts have higher precedence than shift.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define number 0x44332211u

int main()
{
  uint8_t array[4] = 
  {
    (uint8_t)(number >> 24),
    (uint8_t)(number >> 16),
    (uint8_t)(number >>  8),
    (uint8_t) number 
  };

  printf("array[%x] \n\r",array[0]);  // 0x44
  printf("array[%x] \n\r",array[1]);  // 0x33
  printf("array[%x] \n\r",array[2]);  // 0x22
  printf("array[%x] \n\r",array[3]);  // 0x11

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great! it is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a cast in any way. You have defined a constant and compute the values of the array based on that constant. Keep in mind that in this case, the preprocessor simply does a search and replace, nothing clever.

Also, your shift is in the wrong direction. You keep the last (rightmost) 8 bits when casting int to uint8_t, not the first (leftmost) ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are casting an `int` to a `uint8_t`. The only problem is that, when you make the shifts, the result won't fit in the type you are casting to and information will be lost.

Your `uint8_t` casts are just taking the least significant byte. that's why you get 11 in the first case and 0 in the others... because your shifts to the left leave 0 in the rightmost positions.